# Injection of gameobject on scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

So I have gameobject with *GameState* component on it and I have gameobject with *SceneContext*, *GameInstaller* components on it. *GameInstaller* has field for *GameState* also I've referenced *GameInstaller* to monoinstallers. When I'm instantiating player gameobject from prefab - which has [Inject] attribute on *GameState* field, and trying to get access to that verry gameobject on scene with *GameState* component - I'm getting null refs.

thats how I'm [binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD0Dn.png), and that's how i'm [injecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPeLd.png) (it's base class of my enemies/player)

```
public class GroundEnemy : AbstractUnit

    public override void SetDefaultConfig(UnitData groundEnemyData, Camera camera, Player target)
{
    Debug.Log(gameState + " - gamestate ref in " + this.name);
    this.target = target;
    healthbarCanvas.worldCamera = camera;
    maxHealth = currentHealth = groundEnemyData.Health;
    speed = groundEnemyData.UnitSpeed;
    collisionDamage = groundEnemyData.UnitColisionDmg;
    gameState.OnGameLost.AddListener(this.LostGame);
}
```

Well in line with gameState.OnGameLost - i have a null ref.
Injection of *GameState* I'm making in base class, that derives from monobeh.

And thats how i'm instantiating prefabs with player/enemy scripts

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour

{
[InjectOptional] private Player injectedPlayer;
[SerializeField] private LevelLoader levelLoader;
[SerializeField] private CameraTracker camTracker;    
[SerializeField] private Joystick joystick;
[Inject(Id = "Player")] private UnitData playerEntity;
[Inject(Id = "Fly Enemy")] private UnitData flyEntity;
[Inject(Id = "Ground Enemy")] private UnitData groundEntity;
[Inject(Id = "Boss Enemy")] private UnitData bossEntity;
[Inject] private ArenaData arenaData;
[Inject] private GameState gameState;
[Header("Prefabs")]
[SerializeField] private Player playerPrefab;
[SerializeField] private FlyEnemy flyEnemyPrefab;
[SerializeField] private GroundEnemy groundEnemyPrefab;
[SerializeField] private BossEnemy bossEnemyPrefab;
[HideInInspector] public List<AbstractUnit> AliveEnemies = new List<AbstractUnit>();
private Player cashedPlayer;

private void Start()
{
    InstantiateEntities();
}

private void InstantiateEntities()
{
    if (injectedPlayer != null)
    {
        var player = Instantiate(injectedPlayer, arenaData.PlayerSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        player.HealthbarCanvas = camTracker.PriorCamera;
        ExtraSetup(player);
    }
    else
    {
        var player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, arenaData.PlayerSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        player.SetDefaultConfig(playerEntity, camTracker.PriorCamera);
        ExtraSetup(player);
    }

    if (arenaData.FlySpawnPoints.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arenaData.FlySpawnPoints.Count; i++)
        {
            var entity = Instantiate(flyEnemyPrefab, arenaData.FlySpawnPoints[i], Quaternion.identity);
            AliveEnemies.Add(entity);
            entity.SetDefaultConfig(flyEntity, camTracker.PriorCamera, cashedPlayer);
        }
    }

    if (arenaData.GroundSpawnPoints.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arenaData.GroundSpawnPoints.Count; i++)
        {
            var entity = Instantiate(groundEnemyPrefab, arenaData.GroundSpawnPoints[i], Quaternion.identity);
            AliveEnemies.Add(entity);
            entity.SetDefaultConfig(groundEntity, camTracker.PriorCamera, cashedPlayer);
        }
    }

    if (arenaData.BossSpawnPos != Vector2.zero)
    {
        var entity = Instantiate(bossEnemyPrefab, arenaData.BossSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        AliveEnemies.Add(entity);
        entity.SetDefaultConfig(bossEntity, camTracker.PriorCamera, cashedPlayer);
    }
}

private void ExtraSetup(Player player) 
{
    camTracker.SetTarget(player.transform);
    joystick.player = player;
    joystick.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    cashedPlayer = player;
}

public void RemoveEnemy(AbstractUnit abstractUnit)
{
    AliveEnemies.Remove(abstractUnit);
    if (AliveEnemies.IsEmpty())
    {
        gameState.OnPlayerWinLvl?.Invoke();
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1 != SceneManager.sceneCount)
        {
            StartCoroutine(levelLoader.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, cashedPlayer));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please post code samples as embedded code (hit CTRL+K or mark as Code) within the question instead of attaching screenshots

Comment: gave additional code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind FromInstance, like this:

```
Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<GameState>().FromInstance(_myGameStateReference).AsSingle();
```

Comment: Well now my injection to objects that are already on scene works good, but for objects that i'm creating dynamicaly - they still don't get injection.

Comment: Type `Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<GameState>().From` and see, what IDE suggested - there are a bunch of variants, just select the right one. For example, "FromComponentOnPrefab", or "FromComponentOnNewGameObject".

Comment: Well I've found the solution. Injection called only on startup of the scene, for objects that are created dynamicaly for example from a prefab - the prefab should have Zenject auto inject component or that prefab should be created through zenject factory